# Should we store Japanese/French and other non-ASCII characters in java source code?

Tags: java

I am using some Japanese/French words in some regular expressions inside my source code. I don't want to convert these into \u notation since tracking it would be difficult and might introduce bugs hard to catch.

Do we have any standard practice to deal with non-ASCII characters in source code or is it OK to use them as they are.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of storing these regexes in the source, could you pull them out to an external file and compile the regex from strings? This smells like an i18n problem, you have some strings for different languages that need to be tracked and stored they should not be in source they should be external resources.

Comment: Be careful. The day you switch development platform you characters Will break!

Comment: While I agree with @Thorbj0rn, I would wait and see what others have to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's somewhat risky since the program behaviour now depends on the platform default encoding of the machine the program is compiled on, or the compiler arguments. And that makes for hard-to catch bugs, too.

If there are just a handful of such regexes, I'd prefer using the Unicode escapes. If there are a lot, I'd bite the bullet and use UTF-8 of the source code, but only after I have

- A build script (and the app is built only with that script) that uses UTF-8 for the compilation
- Some unit tests that confirm that the regexes are working correctly
- An automated build server that runs the unit tests for every build

Answer (score 1):

Java source code is considered to be encoded in ASCII unless specified otherwise with the `-encoding` switch:

```
javac -encoding utf8 SourceFile.java
```

So, use this and set your text editor to UTF-8 encoding and you can include any Unicode characters you like.

Comment: This is wrong. The (Sun/Oracle) Java compilers uses the platform default encoding.

Comment: I'll re-phrase the question. Is it a bad practice to introduce more than just ASCII characters in source code?

Comment: @Greg: I'd retract the -1, but SO does not seem to consider the answer edited, so I can't...

Comment: As of now I fixed by making my ant build to use utf8 encoding for source. I'll move the non-ASCII chars in resource files and load at run time.
Thanks